# featuretools timeseries data group by month year

Tags: featuretools

I have timeseries data with application number, loan amount. How do I get group by count of applications and average loan amount using featuretools package without adding a relationship of month year back to main entity?

I have already accomplished this using pandas but I am trying to explore featuretools package and was wondering if it has group by like functionality.

Below the example of pandas version: I want to replicate it using featuretools.

```
#Creating a copy of the existing data frame
new_df=df[:] 

#Creating values
new_df['year'] = new_df['DATE'].dt.year
new_df['month'] = new_df['DATE'].dt.month

#Sorting Values
new_df=new_df.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by=['var_1','var2','year','month'])

#Counting Distinct variable across 4 variables then taking cummulative sum across 2 variables and storing it in a new data frame
new_df_count_cummulative=new_df.groupby(['var_1','var_2','year','month']).var_3.nunique().groupby(['var_1','var_2']).cumsum()
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you share more details about the dataset you are using and you're existing pandas code?

Comment: @MaxKanter Just edited the question to include the pandas code.

Comment: @Greg Does my updated question add more clarity?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tools, but could it be chunking that you are looking for? https://docs.featuretools.com/guides/chunking.html